# when should i use sql view

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

we have a table with 2 million records with PK userid and not unique field "Company" we have 35,000 select query an hour to check if a userid exists in our db and what companies he is related to.

should we run the high amount of query on the main table or should we create a view with only userID and company fields and run the query against it?

what are the upside and downside?

i will appreciate your help!

P.s 
the 35,000 queries an hour are with random userid, and change every time.
the user id and company are not updated but we add about 20,000 new rows a day.
my major concern is minimize the response time of the selects even if i do updates to other fields of the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a VIEW will not help.  It will simply reference the underlying table every time you use it.

What might help is to create a *covering index* on the columns you query.  Assuming you only need UserID and Company:

```
 CREATE INDEX <Name> ON <Table> (UserID, Company)
```

Now, queries of the form

```
SELECT Company FROM <Table> WHERE UserID = <Value>
```

can be satisfied from the index without reference to the table data.  This will probably improve your performance (on SELECTs).

Comment: if i will use index, will an update on other fields in the table will cause the select to stall?

Comment: An UPDATE involving UserID or Company, or any INSERT or DELETE statement will require the index to be UPDATEd and a SELECT at that instant would have to wait for the index update.  But that kind of concurrency is what SQL databases excel at (or *should* excel at, you may need to test your exact scenario).

Answer (score 2):

Views will still query the main table, so there's no performance improvement.  They are primarily used for

1. secure access to only those rows/columns authorized,
2. simplify the client SQL if complex joins are needed.

We need to know what your concerns are before we can answer the pros and cons of either direction.

Comment: thanks dlgrasse, my concern is that the table need to be updated about 500 times an hour and i don't want the update to delay the selects since i need a quick response.

Comment: Actually, my main reason to use views is *encapsulation of logic* so that I can use that logic throughout an application without repeating it.

Answer (score 1):

A `View` is nothing more then `queryable queries`. I will suggest that You should create a view with only userID and company fields and run the query against it. However views will also query the existing table.

Some `points` to remember about using views are:

1. A view is really nothing more than a stored select statment
2. The data of a view is the data of tables referenced by the View.
3. creating an index on a view will not work as of the current version
4. If merge algorithm is used, then indexes of underlying tables will
   be used.
5. The underlying indices are not visible, however. DESCRIBE on a view 
   will show no indexed columns.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks AlphaMale, my concern is that the table need to be updated about 500 times an hour and i don't want the update to delay the selects since i need a quick response. will the view help here?

Answer (score 1):

As @dlgrasse said `views` will not help you.

The thing which could help you with these 35000 queries is **having a lot of them already stored in the query cache**. This could happen if in the same hour the queries are usually done on the same users. The other point to get the queries runned on the query cache is to **avoid editing** (insert/update/delete) rows from this big table, after each edit all queries from the query cache implying this table will be invalidated.

So if you have other columns on this table that needs some work but you still want to get a 'fast view' on the user_id and company fields which are not moving a lot, then you could create a dedicated table, containing only those fields, and where the editions are limited.

Comment: thanks regilero , the table users and companies are not changing but every day we add about 20,000 new entries. regarding the 35,000 they are very random and can be different every hour. can i cache only this two column in a temporary table? will it help?

Comment: If the whole table is only updated once a day you'll have no gain with a dedicated table. Checks for gain by using a lot of RAM and try to have most of your data in the innodb buffer pool size